# Excluding some roles from accessing some url in web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, web.xml

Suppose i have 3 roles admin and guest
and i have 40 pages

```
--views
------page1.xhtml1
------page1.xhtml2
------page1.xhtml3
------page1.xhtml4
------ ......
```

admin can access all pages
guest can't access only pages 1,2 and 3
how can i exclude role guest from accessing pages 1,2 and 3

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>excluded</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>No Access</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/views/page1.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/views/page2.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/views/page3.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint />
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

this code sample will stop access for all roles to pages 1,2 and 3 but what i want is to stop access of these pages for role guest only

Comment: "admin and guest" are 2 roles, not 3.

Comment: How many roles are there? Are *all* roles required to be authenticated? Or is it only *one* role which - after authentication - may access certain pages?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the roles in `<auth-constraint>`. This way nobody is able to access those resources. You need to set there the roles which are allowed to access those resources. Provided that your admin role is called exactly like this `admin`, then this should do:

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Don't forget to register the role as `<security-role>` if not done yet:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 Tutorial - Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to configure a security realm in your servlet container, that will allow the container to perform authentication against a database, LDAP server, plain text file, etc. Look at the documentation of your servlet container as this is something really specific to each one.

Then, you must login configuration to your `web.xml`, as a starting point you would be happy enough with a `BASIC` login type (to verify that the container is authenticating users properly) but later one you'll want to have your own login form. Basic login config is something like this:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

*Notice that you have to set there the name of you actual security realm, the one configured in the servlet container.*

Then is when you configure the access using `<security-constraint />` tags (what you have in your current snippet). If you want to allow access to some parts of your app just to some users then you need to add role names to your `<auth-constraint />` tag. Something like the following:

```
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
  <role-name>MODERATOR</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

You'll need to configure the security roles as well:

```
<security-role>ADMIN</security-role>
<security-role>MODERATOR</security-role>
```

Some containers will even require you to add some servlet-specific configuration file to your `/WEB-INF` folder in which you map the actual user groups in your security realm to role names in your application (they can be the same names, but they don't have too). Again, this is servlet container specific so you'll need to check the configuration of your servlet container.

I'm adding some links for further reading:

- [Securing Web Applications](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/security/thin_client.html&ei=h4wcUpSRJYSQ0AXJw4CgAg&usg=AFQjCNEr3wX4TRd_iQYSbAVSFIMdS0zwxA&sig2=elg5fr8hyLN7HVXt_gvjag&bvm=bv.51156542,d.d2k)
- [Understanding Web Security using web.xml](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security&ei=h4wcUpSRJYSQ0AXJw4CgAg&usg=AFQjCNEB34xvtmWS1kc-11ts72QLLTrajw&sig2=T0UcAT1P0wThGnx9z4ZR4w&bvm=bv.51156542,d.d2k)

Comment: all what you have said is correct and is implemented my problem is that i want guest role to access all pages except pages 1,2 and 3 and role admin can access all pages

Comment: then it should be as simple as adding the other roles to the `<auth-constraint/>` section. Sadly, there is no way of telling the container that you want all roles but `X`